# Extern "C" error expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'

Tags: c++, c, extern, nrf52

I am trying to include a compiled library into a C project on a Nordic nrf52840. Below (as far as I understand) is a way to link to some of the methods `foo` and `bar` within the `.lib` file for the rest of the project. When Trying to compile this with Segger Embedded Studio I get the following `expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'int'` error with the following code snippet:

```
#ifndef _FOOBAR_SERVICE_H_
#define _FOOBAR_SERVICE_H_

#if (defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(ARDUINO) || 
defined(__MSP430FR5969__))
#define IMPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
#define LOCAL  __attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))
#elif defined(_WIN32)
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

#include <stdbool.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus

extern "C"
{
#endif

EXPORT int ble_foo(unsigned char  *a, unsigned char *buffer);  //<--(error)

EXPORT int ble_bar(unsigned char  *b, unsigned char *buffer);  //<--(same error)

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif /* _FOOBAR_SERVICE_H_ */
```

The above is `#include "foobar_ble.h"` included in my `main.c` file.

Part of it might be my misunderstanding of `extern "C"` I believe it to be a way of compiling the C code. I believe the `#ifdef __cplusplus` is checking to compile as c++ so would this mean that `extern "C"` is not even utilized within a C environment?

Also, I cannot seem to find a good explanation of the `EXPORT` keyword within C. This could also be a source of my problems.

Tl;dr: Too dumb, too many questions, need help. Plz & thanks.

Comment: `EXPORT` isn't a language keyword. It's usually a preprocessor macro you need to define (or that should be defined for you by the relevant library header).

Comment: Ahh ok. I see what you're saying. Let me update my question

Comment: Looks to me like your compiler isn't one that is supported by the thing you are trying to compile. As a result, it doesn't hit any of those preprocessor conditions and never defines `EXPORT` or it's hitting one that isn't appropriate and expands to something your compiler can't handle.

Comment: That might be the case. I think the library I have was compiled for the Ti cc2640 so that is probably the case. I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_FOOBAR_SERVICE_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker by "reserved for use by the implementation" would you be referring to something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326614/5184092 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/5184092 (the latter probably being more thorough)

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that `EXPORT` in your case isn't defined to anything. So it will just stay in the source code and cause a syntax error. It is probably intended to be defined to something like __declspec(dllexport) on static libraries, and to nothing (empty string) for static usage.

You should be able to fix it by defining `EXPORT` to an empty string. Depending on the library there might be a place for that in some configuration header file. Otherwise you can also use a define on compiler invocation level, but that might not be preferable, since it removes all `EXPORT` words from the source code.